# Does the identity matrix adapt to any other matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

So I have a matrix of the form $X=AX+B$

Where $X$ is a 3 by 1 column matrix, $A$ is a 3 by 3 matrix and $B$ is a 3 by 1 column matrix.

(Notice that I am talking about Leontief input-output).

So I re-arrange and get $X=(I-A)^{-1}+B$ and the book tells me that the identity matrix is a 3 by 3 matrix (so I can subtract $A$ I assume).

But before it got 'coupled' with $A$ it was of the form $IX$ and therefore presumably a 3 by 1 column matrix. Did $I$ 'change' to adapt to $A$ or what is happening here, exactly?

Comment: The rearrangement leads to $(I - A)X = B$, or $X = (I - A)^{-1}B$, so that the multiplication *does* make sense.

Comment: Yes, but when they are at the form $IX-AX=B$ then I don't suppose that $I$ is a 3 by 3 matrix, seeing as X is a 1 by 3.

Answer (score 1):

When you "rearrange" you should get:

$$ (I-A)X = B $$

$$ X = (I-A)^{-1} B $$

assuming that in the second step $I-A$ is actually invertible.

Notice that we have both sides expressing $3\times 1$ columns, rather than the "1 by 3" column mentioned.

Column vectors are matrices with a single column (and likely multiple rows).  Matrix multiplication $AX$ is defined when $A$ has size $m\times n$ and $X$ has size $n\times k$.  In this case we have $m=n=3$ and $k=1$, so matrix multiplication is properly defined.

An identity matrix $I$ needs to be square (equal number of rows as columns), so if more generally $X$ was $n\times 1$, we'd want the identity to have $n$ rows and $n$ columns as well.

Comment: When the equation is on the form: $IX-AX=B$ what size/dimensions is the identity matrix at this point?

Comment: Assuming $X$ is a column with three rows (aka $3\times 1$ matrix), the "identity" $I$ is as you say, a $3\times 3$ matrix.  We call $I$ the identity matrix because it's a multiplicative identity $X = IX$ for appropriate sizes of matrices.

Comment: So the size of the identity matrix $I$ is determined by the rows of it's corresponding matrix? If $X$ was a $4 x 1$ column matrix, then $I$ would be a $4 x 4$ identity matrix?

Comment: @Paze, using just $I$ to denote the identity matrix is a notational shorthand that only works rigorously in limited contexts (when you're working with vector spaces that all have the same dimension). More generally, $I_n$ is used to mean the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: @Paze: Short answer yes.  Since $A$ was a (square) matrix of a size ($3\times 3$) that properly multiplies column vector $X$, what is left to the Reader's understanding is that this identity $I$ is the same size as $A$ (and thus also properly multiplies $X = IX$).  If $X$ were some other size column vector, the sizes of $A$ and $I$ would need to stay consistent with that.